# Passing an IEnumerable result to dropdown list in a ViewComponent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My aim is to get a list of locations (i.e "sites") from a database and display them in a dropdown (html select element) in the _Layout using a ViewComponent, however I receive the following error:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentResult'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

VIEW COMPONENT Class [SiteID.cs]
(PortalContext is my DbContext)

```
namespace XX.Views.Shared.Components
{
    [ViewComponent(Name = "SiteIDsDropDown")]
    public class SiteIDsDropDownViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private ILogger logger;
        private PortalContext context;

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(ILogger<SecureController> logger, PortalContext context)
    {
        var _logger = logger;
        var _context = context;

        var results = (from s in _context.Sites
                        select new SiteViewModel
                        {
                            ID = s.ID,
                            Description = s.Description
                        }).ToList();
        return results;
    } 
}
```

VIEW COMPONENT Partial View [~/Views/Shared/Component/SiteIDsDropDownViewComponent/default.cshtml]

```
@model IEnumerable<XX.ViewModels.SiteIDViewModel>     
<select>
    <option>Please select and item</option>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option>@item.ID</option>
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return result should be View(results), So change your method accordingly.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(ILogger<SecureController> logger, PortalContext context)
{
    var _logger = logger;
    var _context = context;

    var results = (from s in _context.Sites
                    select new SiteViewModel
                    {
                        ID = s.ID,
                        Description = s.Description
                    }).ToList();
    return View(results);
}
```

Comment: This results in an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can you please check stack trace where it is throwing error?